# Use of parentheses when writing a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Why while writing a function sometimes I need to write within parentheses and sometime I don't? For example `function get arr()` vs `function get max(arr)`.
Thanks,
A

Comment: you pass in parameters within the parenthesis. If a function doesn't take any, then you still need the parenthesis to signify the function call.

Comment: everything between these parentheses are parameters you need them for this function, for the function get_max you have to receive a number to return the max value between them.

Comment: In your example, arr() is a function that doesn't take parameters, and max() is a function that takes 1 parameter, in this case some variable with the name "arr". The word "function" is only written when you declare a function, not when you call one.

Comment: Why is there a `get` before function name and parameters in parentheses?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: Thx! About to start a coding bootcamp and am new to the basic concepts. Would like to utilize and try out different information sources. Hope there is enough place under the sun of stack overflow for all, regardless of experience and knowledge ;-)

Comment: There's plenty of space, but you need to understand that SO will not function as a good source of basic training and tutorial information. For that you should look to any of the great resources on the web in the form of books and tutorials. SO is more oriented to answering relatively specific programming problems, so when you get to that point in your learning process, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function with anything inside paranthesis you are giving in the parameters.

And when you are not passing anything you simply keep the parenthsis blank like this ().

Eg :

```
function add(a,b){ //passing arguments
  return a+b;
}

add(15,13); // returns 28


function name(){ //not passing arguments
  return 'hello world';
}
name(); // returns 'hello world'
```

In your second case you are passing in function as argument to another function.

Please comment something if you need something more because it is not very clear with your question what you wanted to ask.

Comment: I am very new to coding. Thank you this answers it!

Comment: please do also read about properly closing lines with semicolons (that goes for Invictus as well) ;)   (semicolons edited in later)